# I am loosing stylings when I use media query in my CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

Hi I am using media query in my application to make webpages responsive. I never used this before. 
I am using media query in my CSS like below :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 70em) {
div.MoreInfoterms {

    width: 800px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    background-color: #f7f9f9;
    max-height: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
}
```

And this is my HTML :

```
<div class="MoreInfoterms">
        <ul>
            <li> <p> This App has no minimum term.</p> </li>
               <li> <p>This App has no minimum term.</p> </li>
                <li> <p>This App has no minimum term..</p> </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LBuTj

Here in both cases when I minimize browser and when media query starts to take effect then I am able to see only contents without styles. So can someone help me in this?

Comment: You have two identical queries there. Is that intentional? It's going to be difficult to see what's happening without your HTML sample.

Comment: @isherwood Hi sorry for confusion. I placed only one media query with HTML. please have a look into my post.

Comment: Fiddle added above. Please explain what's not working. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LBuTj

Comment: @Ajay: Instead of min-width you have to use max-width...

Comment: I might be not well-informed but why do you rely on `em` units when trying to determine the device's width?

Comment: @isherwood that gray color background which i am using will be lost when i minimize page. you can also check

Comment: I think @Ani is right in that you have to use max-width instead of min-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40em)
```

You're setting the elements with styles if the browsers size is more than `40em`. So to do the complement function you can set styles off the media query declaration or make a new one:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em)
```

View this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/LBuTj/2/**

Comment: What you showed make sense. Appreciate your time. But is this the way I should do everytime? I mean when mediaquery has no effects then separate styles in min-width and separate styles into max-width if I need to change position?

Comment: Nop the better way to do this is -- setting default styles for all the site and after set with `@media screen and (max-width: 40em)` the specific property that you want to change.

Comment: Hi thanks again. I have one doubt. Say for example, I have two tables placed on left side and right side of page, without using media query. Now if i need my 2nd table to flow below first table when user minimize browser, then if i am not wrong, I need to make separate class with media query and define width and height based on my need. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I moved this into a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/AVABaZEl/1/edit?html,css,output) so you can see the queries respond in the output. Essentially your CSS is scoping the styles to only apply if the width of the viewport is > 40em. Anything below 40em does not have any styles.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. So how can i make my styles work even width is below minimum?

Comment: Styles that aren't wrapped in a media query will fire for any width, you can then add in the styles you need with min-width queries as the browser gets bigger. That way every viewport width is styled.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 70em) { //instead use (max-width: 400px/ or whatever you want.)

    div.MoreInfoterms {

          width: 800px;
          margin-right: 250px;
          margin-left: 55px;
          margin-top: 20px;
          border: 1px solid #cecece;
          background-color: #f7f9f9;
          max-height: 700px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

}

Also, I would suggest to use `px` instead of `em` when defining media queries